# Style of user-defined C++ types in VS Code

Tags: themes, syntax-highlighting, visual-studio-code

C++ code, VS Code 1.3 with MS cpp_tools. Have UD type which has names like `typename_t` (like `size_t`, `ssize_t` etc).

With Solarized Dark theme it looks like this:

[image]

So UD types are not types, and different from, say, float - looks like keywords(?)

Ok, switch to Abyss theme

[image]

Same code, but here I have UD types clearly in the same style as basic types like `float`

Could someone shed a light on why there is such difference? Is it possible to
have UD types in the same style as basic type in the Solazired Dark theme (which I prefer greatly to anything else)?

Comment: We don't have the _too localized_ close reason anymore so, I've just added some tags narrowing your question. Least it has to do with is the c++ language itself (tempted to remove that tag).

Comment: Isn't the difference simply that the theme is defining distinct colors in one case, and not the other? Even with Solarized Dark, there is a difference because the built-in types are bold. The obvious fix to your problem is to edit the theme, I have no idea how to go about doing that.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ ok, removed c++ tag, np.

Comment: @Praetorian well, that's how I think it supposed work - theme defines styles for common tags (constant, numeric, string, type decl, function name), and language support parser supplies tags with each word parsed. I would suspect language support supplied different tags for basic and UD types, but what are they? List of tags?

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux _" ok, removed c++ tag, np"_ A probably good decision! Now it's jus about you're going to show some expertise how to use these themes or adapt them for your personalized features.